# Call a sub from a function in Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

My MS Access application has a subroutine which fires after I update one control on a form.

```
Public Sub cboCrew_AfterUpdate()
    ...do some work...
End Sub
```

I would like to call this same sub from a function I have defined in Module1

```
Function my_function()
     Call cboCrew_AfterUpdate
End Function
```

This code throws the error: "Compile Error  Sub or Function not defined"

I suspect that the problem is that I am not being specific enough, in my call to the sub.
Do I need to reference the sub with `"some_modulte_name.sub_name"` ?
Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this up the other way around...

```
Public Sub cboCrew_AfterUpdate()
    My_Function
End Sub

Function my_function(frm As Form)
     ''Do stuff
End Function
```

Re comment

```
Public Sub cboCrew_AfterUpdate()
    My_Function Me 
End Sub

Function my_function(frm As Form)
     MsgBox frm.Name
End Function

Sub AnotherSub()
   My_Function Forms!AFormName
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a clever approach. Unfortunately it won't help.  You see I need to make {public sub cboCrew_afterUpdate()} fire.  In your solution, it is firing already.

Comment: It is not particularly clever, it is a standard approach. When an event fires, actions are carried out. How do you see making after update fire as any different from carrying out these same actions in another function?

Comment: The question I've asked is "how to call a sub from a function."  
the reason I asked this is because I need an existing Sub to fire upon another event.
Obviously, the sub already fires (after the update event).
But I would like to call the sub at another time, during another event.  Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have found out how to reference the sub.